# Did the way quotation marks are used, change at some point, in the past 100 years?

Tags: etymology, punctuation

I hope this question is allowed - I'm considering it question from an etymological standpoint :)

I have noticed that on vintage signs / memorabilia / magazines, phrases or words are quoted, seemingly for no reason. They almost appear to be used how we would use an underline or exclamation point today, something like the below (though usage varies):

> I hate "doing laundry"

Anecdotally, I've noticed older folks (60+) occasionally using quotation marks in this same fashion on social media. It always stumps me, as I've grown up always reading them as either (obviously) demarcation of a quote, or as mocking/scare quotes.

I've added some reference images below. For the second one, look to the bottom right corner.

[image: vintage 7up advertisement]
[image: vintage book cover]

Comment: The use of quotation marks has been all over the map since before the invention of the printing press.  Very often quotes are used as a form of emphasis (though less so in the computer era since *italics* have become more accesible).

Comment: I don't understand your illustrations. The use of "fresh up" in quotation marks is clearly self-quotation — this was 7up's slogan at the time. As for the second ad, perhaps it's probably because the woman looks somewhat like a different professional.

Answer (score 1):

At least in older print, it's certainly true that this usage is quite common. You can definitely see it in older literature (earlier than the 1950s) where modern editing processes have not altered much of the punctuation choices when reissuing literature.

It's probably more correct to say that in present day, this usage has fallen out of favor for other ways of expressing emphasis. Today, we may favor italicizing, making bold, underlining, using all caps, or some other way to express emphasis because it is easy to do, whereas printing presses of the past may have had difficulty with or simply did not have these functions. So, in order to express emphasis, quotation marks were used.

As a result, today, quotation marks are almost exclusively used for direct quoting literature or the words of someone. But, there is no discrete rule that they cannot be used for other purposes such as providing emphasis.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard, regular, official, "correct" way to use quotation marks or any other [punctuation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-Punctuation.pdf). Quotation marks are subject to great variability in use and purpose, like all punctuation, and they change quite fast. Shakespeare's punctuation, for instance, would get any modern student an F in English.

The particular use of quotes highlighted above appears to be an attempt to transcribe -- or to echo in the mind's ear of the reader -- the flatted ironic intonation curve that American English speakers use to accompany "air quotes" made with the fingers, meaning that the phrase being "quoted" is not exactly correct, and may in fact be a euphemism. This is merely one among many other uses -- irony is pretty widespread in the United States at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

I wish that no one used quotation marks this way any more.

Inappropriate quotation marks are one of my pet peeves.  They're actually quite common.

On my way to work, I used to pass an ice rink that has a sign that says, "Come in and 'learn to skate'" and wonder what *really* goes on in there.

If you search for "inappropriate quotation marks" you'll find hundreds of images. Here's a blog dedicated to cataloging some of the funnier uses: *[The "Blog" of "Unnecessary" Quotation Marks](http://www.unnecessaryquotes.com/search?updated-max=2015-08-24T08:39:00-05:00&max-results=10&start=10&by-date=false)*